# Kotlin println special characters

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, special-characters, println

I want to print some special characters(Latin, Greek alphabet, Chinese, etc) in Kotlin, but always got `???????` as the output:

```
>> println("Δ")
>> ??????
```

Also tried unicode:

```
>> println("\u0394")
>> ?
```

IDE I used: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.3.

Console I used: Kotlin REPL.

jdk: 9.0.4

Kotlin version: 1.2.31 (JRE 9.0.4+11)

How could I print the right string?

---

Update(20180512):

I also tried to install Kotlin via Homebrew and run `kotlinc` in my own terminal, it works as expected. It just doesn't work in Kotlin REPL of IntelliJ. Any place I can go to fix that?

---

Update(20180513):

Tried the followings:

1. Clear IntelliJ cache;
2. Reinstalled IntelliJ;
3. Make IntelliJ and Kotlin up to date;
4. Restart MacOS(10.12.6);
5. Update Java to 10.0.1.

Used `println` in Kotlin REPL again, `???` changed to the specific error:

```
println("Δ")
Internal error occurred. Please, send report to developers.
exception: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
    at kotlin.io.ConsoleKt.tryDecode(Console.kt:198)
    at kotlin.io.ConsoleKt.readLine(Console.kt:162)
    at kotlin.io.ConsoleKt.readLine(Console.kt:149)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.repl.reader.IdeReplCommandReader.readLine(IdeReplCommandReader.kt:22)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.repl.ReplFromTerminal.one(ReplFromTerminal.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.repl.ReplFromTerminal.doRun(ReplFromTerminal.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.repl.ReplFromTerminal.access$doRun(ReplFromTerminal.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.repl.ReplFromTerminal$Companion.run(ReplFromTerminal.kt:175)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:171)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:162)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:329)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)

Internal error occurred. Please, send report to developers.

Process finished with exit code 2
```

It seems the reading character encoding is different from writing encoding. But I can find no way to config the encoding of Kotlin REPL.

And also, I found 2 java processes running while I open Kotlin REPL and **every time I have to kill one to run Kotlin REPL smoothly**:

[image: 2 java processes running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9jda.png)

I'm not sure if they are related, so I attached the image as a reference. Already reported to IntelliJ developers, but it seems not a common bug for most people.

Comment: Copy and pasting that into IntelliI, it works fine for me. Perhaps it's a platform issue?

Comment: try to change the encoding in intellij settings to UTF-8

Comment: @msrd0 I used utf-8 as the global encoding as well as the project encoding, but still not working. Also, I used Kotlin REPL console so there's no file created when the error appears...

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `println("\u0394")`. If that works, your file likely isn't in the UTF-8 encoding. If it doesn't, there's an issue with your terminal.

Comment: If OP can open the file after saving and still see the character, then the problem can't be on the level of source code. It could be, though, in mismatched encoding between editor and compiler.

Comment: Thanks @Cristan. I tried using unicode but still failed... But it works when I use my own terminal by downloading the [Command Line Compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html#homebrew). It just doesn't work in Kotlin REPL of IntelliJ... Any ideas of IntelliJ configuration?

Comment: @y.bedrov Thanks, will do :)